# Using 3rd party windows DLL written in VS C++ from Go program

Tags: winapi, dll, go

I have .lib, .h and .dll files of 3rd party windows library written in C++ (using Visual Studio compiller)

How is it possible to use such .dll from Go program? Is it possible at all if cgo is using MinGW C++?

Can you please point to any examples online? I've tried calling native Windows DLLs using `syscall.NewLazyDLL()` but it didn't work for 3rd party DLLs.

Thanks!

I get errors like:

`C:\DOCUME~1\Alex\LOCALS~1\Temp\go-build023179027\zelid\gowingui.a(_all.o): malformed pe file: unexpected flags 0xe0500020 for PE section .text`

`C:\DOCUME~1\Alex\LOCALS~1\Temp\go-build404633023\zelid\gowingui.a(_all.o): malformed pe file: unexpected flags 0xe0500020 for PE section .text
main._Cfunc_HTMLayoutProcND: undefined: _cgo_c2d779df8b44_Cfunc_HTMLayoutProcND`

`$ gcc --version
gcc (tdm-2) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.`

`$ go version
go version go1.3.3 windows/386`

Comment: Maybe https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=5106#c16 could help. Otherwise https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=4069 is still opened.

Comment: I use 32bit MinGW and there are no such lib. I've tried suggestions from https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=5106 nothing helps